# Obtener solo un dato de un Spinner que tiene dos datos en Android

Tags: mysql, android, android-spinner

Buen día, espero que la pregunta se comprenda, resulta que estoy llenando un *spinner* desde *MySQL* en el cual necesito traer un nombre y un precio esto lo hago correctamente pero al momento de obtener lo que contiene el *spinner* me trae los dos datos el nombre y el precio entonces necesito que solo me traiga el precio esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

Para ello utilizo la siguiente librería:

```
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

Declaro las variables a utilizar

```
private AsyncHttpClient cliente;
private Spinner spColonias;
```

inicializo dichas variables

```
spColonias = findViewById(R.id.spinnerColonias);
cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
```

Creo un método para llenar el *spinner* mediante la url (utilizando PHP para la consulta)

```
private void llenarSpinner(){
    String url ="http://"+mi_host+"/llenarColoniasantones.php";
    cliente.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (statusCode == 200){
                cargarSpinner(new String(responseBody));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }

    });
}
```

Y por ultimo cargo el *spinner* con los datos de la base de datos:

```
private void cargarSpinner(String respuesta){

    ArrayList<Colonias> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArreglo = new JSONArray(respuesta);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArreglo.length(); i++){

            Colonias c = new Colonias();
            //En esta parte lleno el spinner con los campos que quiero en este caso serian 2
            c.setNombreColonia(jsonArreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre_colonia"));
            c.setPrecioColonia(jsonArreglo.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("precio_colonia"));

            lista.add(c);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Colonias> a  = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lista);
        spCantones.setAdapter(a);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo el modelo:

```
public class Colonias {

    String nombreColonia;
    int idColonia;
    Double precioColonia;

    public Colonias(){

    }

    public Colonias(String nombreColonia, int idColonia, Double precioColonia) {
        this.nombreColonia = nombreColonia;
        this.idColonia = idColonia;
        this.precioColonia = precioColonia;
    }

    public String getNombreColonia() {
        return nombreColonia;
    }

    public void setNombreColonia(String nombreColonia) {
        this.nombreColonia = nombreColonia;
    }

    public int getIdColonia() {
        return idColonia;
    }

    public void setIdColonia(int idColonia) {
        this.idColonia = idColonia;
    }

    public Double getPrecioColonia() {
        return precioColonia;
    }

    public void setPrecioColonia(Double precioColonia) {
        this.precioColonia = precioColonia;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  nombreColonia + precioColonia;
    }
}
```

El método *toString* es lo que necesito retornar en el *spinner* en este caso es *nombreColonia* y *precioColonia*.

Como ultimo paso he creado una variable estática para obtener el precio desde cualquier parte de la aplicacion:

```
public static String precio;
```

Luego le digo que la variable va a ser igual a lo que se seleccione del *spinner*:

```
precio = spColonias.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Pero cuando obtengo el resultado me trae los dos datos tanto *nombre_colonia* como *precio_colonia*, entonces necesito que solo me traiga el precio y omita la parte de obtener el nombre de la colonia.

Espero que se haya comprendido la pregunta de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Buenas, creo que lo que ocurre es que al hacer esto: spColonias.getSelectedItem().toString(); obtienes un String comuesto. Como ArrayAdapter lo creas como un objeto igual debería probar a recuperar el campo precio: spColonias.getSelectedItem().getPrecioColonia() y no invocar al método toString().

Comment: Hola @FranCámara gracias por la ayuda, como haría para que luego de getSelectedItem me reconozca el getPrecioColonia? esto no me funciona precio = spCantones.getSelectedItem().getPrecioColonia();

Comment: Sólo exponía una idea, si supiese seguro la respuesta, la habría desarrollado mejor, en vez de ponerte un comentario. como el Spinner es un array de tipo Colonias, intenta hacer algo así: Colocias c = spCantones.getSelectedItem(); ponte un punto de para de debug y comprueba si obtienes el objeto entero y entonces intenta recuperar el precio: c.getPrecioColonia();
Si te funciona redacto mejor la respuesta por si le sirve a alguien en el futuro.

Comment: Hola @FranCámara fíjate que ya probé de diferentes maneras pero no funciona aunque ponga c.getPrecioColonia(); siempre me retorna los dos campos

Comment: No puede ser, comprueba en debug que la respuesta JSON te esté llegando bien, y cre un array sólo de los perfumes, para imprimirlos y ver si los estás creando bien. El principio de la POO es que al acceder a un campo, sólo debería devolver el valor de este, y la clase Colonias la tienes bien definida.

Comment: @FranCámara comentarte que ya he logrado un  resultado sin embargo en el sebug solo me trae el primer item que esta en el spinner porque no me traera el que selecciono? final int spinnerp = spCantones.getSelectedItemPosition();
            idd = lista.get(spinnerp).getPrecioColonia();

Comment: Entonces lo fácil y rápido sería dejarlo como lo tienes y cambiar el return del toString de la clase Colonias para devolver sólo el precio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para obtener unicamente el precio lo puedes obtener usando el indice del elemento en el `Spinner` mediante [getSelectedItemPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition()) y usando este indice para obtener el valor del precio.

Primeramente declara el ArrayList de forma que pueda ser leido en toda tu clase:

```
private ArrayList<Colonias> lista = new ArrayList<>();

private void cargarSpinner(String respuesta){

    //ArrayList<Colonias> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Ahora mediante [getSelectedItemPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition())

```
int indice = spCantones.getSelectedItemPosition();
  
String valorPrecio = lista.get(indice).getPrecioColonia();
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu tiempo comentarte que si hago eso no me mostraria en en spinner el nombre de la colonia se veria asi -> null $6.0 por lo tanto necesito esa linea para que se me muestre en el spinner el nombre de la colonia!

Comment: Lo que quieres es que se muestre en el Spinner el nombre y el precio, pero al obtener la informacion del Spinner solo obtengas el precio?

Comment: Asi es @Jorgesys eso es lo que necesito

Comment: Hola Adiel, actualice mi respuesta,

Comment: Hola gracias por la actualización comentarte que ya me esta funcionando muy bien, gracias por tomarte el tiempo!

Comment: Me da gusto funcione Adiel, saludos!